# Probability column 'Probability' not found in FastForest Trainer in ML.net

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

The below code does execute successfully using this trainer:

```
var trainer = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree();
```

But if I use the "FastForest" trainer:

```
var trainer = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastForest();
```

I receive this error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Probability column 'Probability' not found
Parameter name: schema'
```

on the line:

```
var metrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label");
```

From what I have understand and have red is that:
***"If you specifically need probabilities from the FastForest trainer, you would need to apply a calibration method separately to obtain them."***

I have trouble to find an answer of how to add a "calibration method" in my code below when I use the "**FastForest**".

```
var trainer = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastForest();
```

How could that be implemented in this code?

```
    void trainModel()
    {
        // Set up MLContext
        var mlContext = new MLContext();

        // Define database connection parameters
        string databaseName = "AAPL";
        string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=" + databaseName + ";Trusted_Connection=True;";
        var tableName = "AAPL_1day";

        // Get the column names from the database table
        var columnNames = GetColumnNamesFromDatabaseTable(connectionString, tableName);

        // Generate the list of column conditions for IS NOT NULL
        //var columnConditions = columnNames.Select(column => $"{column} IS NOT NULL");
        var columnConditions = columnNames.Select(column => $"[{column}] IS NOT NULL").ToList();

        // Create the SELECT query with the column conditions
        var query = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE {string.Join(" AND ", columnConditions)}";

        // Create the database source with the dynamically generated query
        var databaseSource = new DatabaseSource(SqlClientFactory.Instance, connectionString, query);

        // Load the data from the database
        var loader = mlContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader<AAPLData>();
        var dataView = loader.Load(databaseSource);
        var preview = dataView.Preview();

        // Split the data into train and test sets
        var split = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(dataView, testFraction: 0.35);

        // Define the data preprocessing pipeline
        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "MonthNr", "DayNr", "roc_1", "roc_2")
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType("Features", "Features", DataKind.Single))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("Features"));

        // Define the trainer
        var trainer = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree();

        // Define the training pipeline
        var trainingPipeline = pipeline.Append(trainer);

        // Train the model
        var model = trainingPipeline.Fit(split.TrainSet);

        // Make predictions
        var predictions = model.Transform(split.TestSet);

        // Evaluate the model
        var metrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label");

        // Retrieve the evaluation metrics
        var accuracy = metrics.Accuracy;
        var auc = metrics.AreaUnderRocCurve;

        MessageBox.Show($"Accuracy: {accuracy}\n" + $"AUC: {auc}");
    }
    // Define a class to hold your data
    public class AAPLData
    {
        [LoadColumn(2)] public double MonthNr;
        [LoadColumn(3)] public double DayNr;
        [LoadColumn(4)] public double roc_1;
        [LoadColumn(5)] public double roc_2;
        [LoadColumn(6), ColumnName("Label")] public bool hypo_upordown7days;
    }
    public static List<string> GetColumnNamesFromDatabaseTable(string connectionString, string tableName)
    {
        var columnNames = new List<string>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Get the schema information for the table
            var schemaTable = connection.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { null, null, tableName });
            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                // Extract the column name from the schema table
                var columnName = row["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
                columnNames.Add(columnName);
            }
        }
        return columnNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that using the below line of code, it was possible to return the metrics:

```
        var metrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.EvaluateNonCalibrated(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label");
```

Comment: Thanks this also helped to solve my problem. Really worrying and frustrating to see that ML.NET questions are neglected and ignored on SO. Makes one wonder how serious Microsoft is about growing and supporting this technology?